# How to build a URL from OsStr and str components?

Tags: rust

This code walks a folder, and finds files ending with `.txt`. Next, I want to take the `entry.file_name()` which is of `std::ffi::os_str::OsStr` type, and join it with `BASE_URL` to form a URL.

```rust
const FOLDER_NAME: &str = "/tmp";
const PATTERN: &str = ".txt";
const BASE_URL: &str = "http://192.168.1.100:3310/";

use std::error::Error;
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use walkdir::WalkDir;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    println!("Walking folder {}", FOLDER_NAME);

    let valid_entries = WalkDir::new(FOLDER_NAME)
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|e| e)
        .flat_map(|e| {
            let name = e.file_name().to_str()?;
            if name.contains(PATTERN) {
                Some(e)
            } else {
                None
            }
        });

    print_type_of(&valid_entries);

    for entry in valid_entries {
        println!("This file matches: {:?}", entry);
        let metadata = entry.metadata()?;
        let size = metadata.len();
        let name = entry.file_name();
        let fullpath = entry.path().display();
        println!("path: {}, filename: {:?}, Len: {:?}", fullpath, name, size);
        print_type_of(&name);
        //let url = format!("{}{}",BASE_URL, name); <--- this, how do I do this?
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}
```

Sample output of the blowup:

```
error[E0277]: `std::ffi::OsStr` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
--> src/main.rs:34:38
   |
34 |         let url = format!("{}{}",BASE_URL, name);
   |                                            ^^^^ `std::ffi::OsStr` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `std::ffi::OsStr`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Display` for `&std::ffi::OsStr`
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

In Go, I do this as:

```golang
video_url := baseURL + *video.Name
req, err := http.NewRequest("HEAD", video_url, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Err", err)
}
```

what is the correct method to do this in Rust?

The closest I got was:

```rust
let url = format!("{}{:?}", BASE_URL, name);
println!("url {}", url);
```

which gives:

```
This file matches: DirEntry("/tmp/a.txt")
path: /tmp/a.txt, filename: "a.txt", Len: 820805
&std::ffi::os_str::OsStr
&str
url http://192.168.1.100:3310/"a.txt"  <- malformed
This file matches: DirEntry("/tmp/somefile.txt")
path: /tmp/somefile.txt, filename: "somefile.txt", Len: 13
&std::ffi::os_str::OsStr
&str
url http://192.168.1.100:3310/"somefile.txt" <- malformed
```

with this I've to figure out how to remove the `"`s. Sure feels like there's a better way which I don't know of..

Since the correct method uses a `match` expression, how can I build the URL out of one?

```
let name = entry.file_name();
let name_to_str = entry.file_name().to_str();
let url = match name_to_str {
        Some(name) =>  format!("{}{:?}",BASE_URL, name_to_str).replace("\"", ""),
        _ => None
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_str) method in `OsStr` to get an `Option<&str>`. It returns an `Option` since the conversion might fail if the string doesn't contain valid Unicode. If you are absolutely certain that it will be always be valid Unicode, you can just `unwrap` the `Option`. Thus, you can create your url as follows:

```
let url = format!("{}{}", BASE_URL, name.to_str().unwrap());
```

Edit 1

`{:?}` is meant for debug printing. It uses the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) trait. As the link says, Debug

> should format the output in a programmer-facing, debugging context

It just so happens that in your case, that happens to be the string that you wanted but that is not its intended behavior. I would still recommend using the method `to_str` that has been explicitly provided for your use-case

Comment: This seems to work: `let url = format!("{}{:?}",BASE_URL, name).replace("\"", "");` - any feedback on whether `unwrap` is still preferred? Also, your code example uses `as_str` , I think you typo'd  instead of `to_str`

Comment: Also there is nothing wrong with using `unwrap` if you can provide the guarantees. If you cannot guarantee that the `OsStr` will contain valid Unicode, you can either manually handle both variants of the `Option` or you can also just use the [`to_string_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_string_lossy) method

Comment: Note also that if `name` contains special characters that can't be represented, `{:?}` will escape them in a way that is almost certainly not the one you want.

Comment: I just read elsewhere that  **Code should not be unwrapped in production. Instead, a match statement should be used** --  looking to see how to build my url from match statement's findings.

Comment: Yes since production would imply that other users would use your program and you definitely cannot guarantee whether their path names will be valid Unicode or not

Comment: could you please advise on **Edit 2** above - how to create the url from a match statement?

Comment: You will either need to return an error from the method indicating incorrect input by returning a Result. Or, you could just cause a panic similar to what unwrap would do, or you could just skip past invalid items. There are multiple ways to handle it and you should pick whichever fits your case the best

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the correct type for URL raw data is not really `str`.

Fully encoded URLs, using [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) to encode special characters, are pure ASCII. When you decode it, you get the many parts of the URL (protocol, domain name, the various parts between `'/'`, `'?'`, `'&'`, etc) as uninterpreted binary data (i.e. `[u8]`), not as valid UTF-8 like enforced by `str`/`String`.

To be robust, you may want percent-encode the individual parts of the url directly from the original data. In particular, file names should be URL-encoded directly from the `&OsStr`/`OsString`. This way you don't risk getting non-UTF-8 filenames to break your code, or even worse, filenames with potential dangerous characters, like `?`, `=` and `&` to be an attack vector.

In practice, using crate [urlencoding](https://docs.rs/urlencoding/latest/urlencoding/index.html), it would be something like this:

```
let name = urlencoding::encode_binary(entry.file_name().as_bytes());
```

This will encode the filename exactly as it is represented in your OS. That is, if your OS support `as_bytes()`. Unfortunately, that is not the case for every OS.

That is understandable: I have no idea how to encode a Windows 16-bit `wchar` into an URL if greater than 255. It seems that the convention in this case is to to convert the whole string to UTF-8 before URL-encoding (using `.to_str()`, as the other answer suggests), but then the filename might be an invalid UTF-16, in which case the conversion will fail, and I guess it is really impossible to represent such file name in an URL, and you should return an error in your program (see the [question mark](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/index.html#the-question-mark-operator-) operator).